# Trying to organize my urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My site has different urls for different categories, which returns a filtered queryset based on the category, e.g. `/sport/` will return `Post.objects.filter(category='sport')`

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^news/$', boxes_view, name='news'),
    url(r'^sport/$', boxes_view, name='sport'),
    url(r'^technology/$', boxes_view, name='technology'),
    url(r'^science/$', boxes_view, name='science'),
    url(r'^cars/$', boxes_view, name='cars'),
    url(r'^television/$', boxes_view, name='television'),

    url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/', article, name='article'),
```

view

```
def boxes_view(request):
    category = 'news'
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        name = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
        if b == name:
            category = a

    posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category)
```

choices.py

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'news'),
    ('2', 'sport'),
    ('3', 'technology'),
    ('4', 'science'),
    ('5', 'cars'),
    ('6', 'television')
)
```

Instead of listing every category in my urls, is there anyway I can write just 1 uniform url pattern to account for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact it looks like you're part way there. You can use a regular expression to recognise the category name and pass that to the view just as you have done with the last url in your list ('article').

Try something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/$', boxes_view, name='category'), #or whatever name
    url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/', article, name='article'),
]
```

Then your view will be something like:

```
def boxes_view(request, category='news'):
    try:
        category_number = CATEGORY_MAP[category]
    except KeyError:
        # return 404?
    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category_number)
    ...
```

You'll then need a category map which will be just like your tuple but I would use a dictionary like:

```
CATEGORY_MAP = {
    'news': 1,
    ...
}
```

Although I would need to see more of your schema to be sure, from what I have seen I would suggest that the categories should be their own model and you could then do `category__name` in your `Post` filter and drop the mapping from name to number.

Comment: How are you getting the category value in your try/except code? At the moment i'm getting it by obtaining the last word of the url path, but I can't see how you're getting it using `category_number = CATEGORY_MAP[category]`

Comment: the category is passed in to the view as an argument to the view function. That's what happens when you use regex in Django url patterns.

Comment: Where does the url pattern get the `category`? Would it get it from the template like `{% url 'boxes_view' category='sport' %}` `{% url 'boxes_view' category='technology' %}` ?

Comment: yes, that's how you do it in a url template tag. The url pattern itself gets the key word from the url in the request.

Comment: Alright so i'm finding it abit difficult to do the first method so maybe the model would be easier. How would the model work exactly...do I make a seperate `Category` model and then link it to my `Post` model through `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. However I don't think it will solve the problem you're having as you'll still need to set up the urls and view in a similar way. What are you finding difficult?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137630/discussion-between-chidg-and-zorgan).